# CXF Http Conduit - timeout being ignored (JAVA)

Tags: java, http-headers, cxf

I am creating a HTTPConduit in JAVA programatically and I would like to change the conduit name to ***.http_conduit**

How can I set that?

**Source Code:**

```
Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(port);  
HTTPConduit http = (HTTPConduit) client.getConduit();   
HTTPClientPolicy httpClientPolicy = new HTTPClientPolicy();   
httpClientPolicy.setConnectionTimeout(600000);      
httpClientPolicy.setAllowChunking(false);     
http.setClient(httpClientPolicy);
```

Comment: Any solution for above?
The connection timeout is being ignored and I saw that the conduit name with regular expression able to fix this. However, I am declaring httpConduit in JAVA.